# React.js - child component props undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass data from parent to child component. The data is fetched from API.

Following is the parent component:

```
const App = () => {

  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

      const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
        const data = await response.json();
        setItem(data);
    }

      fetchData();

  }, [])

  const slidedData = item.slice(0, 10);

  const data = slidedData.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.title] = (acc[item.title] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});

    return (
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/child"
              render={() =>
                <Child data={data} />
              }
            />
          </Switch>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And the following is the child component which receives props:

```
const Child = ({ data }) => {

    const test = data.map(el => el);
    console.log(test);

}
```

Above code doesn't work. It says 'TypeError: data.map is not a function'

I understand this is because at the initial render the data is not ready for child component thus 'data' is undefined. What should I do to make this 'data' work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typeOf `data` in `Child` component is not an Array, its an `object` and `.map` is an `array` function, hence the error. Check and log variable `data` instead.

One of the ways to iterate an object is below

```
Object.keys(data).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand why .map didn't work.